# Как получить значения полей?

Tags: jquery, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно записать в массив значения полей этой формы?

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="q" />

    <input type="text" value="3e" />

    <textarea rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
$( function(){
    var arr = [] // Объявим массив

    // Выберем все элементы формы
    $('form').find('input, textarea, select').each( function(){
        // Добавим значение в массив
        arr.push(this.value)                
    })

    alert(arr.join(', '))
})​
```

[Пример 1](http://jsfiddle.net/cuv5v/1/)

А можно и ещё короче :)

```
$( function(){
    var arr = $('form').find('input, textarea, select').map( function(){
        return this.value
    }).get()

    alert(arr.join(', '))
})​
```

[Пример 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j45AT/)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще хорошо использовать **$('form').[serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)**, но этот метод не будет работать без тэга **name**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i in forms) {
    console.log(forms[i].value);
    //или меняем
    forms[i].value = "fill";
}
```

//textarea скрипт захватит